# JMeter Testing Configuration

Tags: jmeter

I am passing a variable using the command line to the Jmeter. How can I read this variable and set it to the enabled attribute. Is there a way to do it. Based on the value passed from the command line (either true or false) i want to enable or disable the test.

I am using 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add an "If controller" to the begining of your "Thread group", set its condition to `${__P(MY_TEST_CASE_ENABLED)}` (where MY_TEST_CASE_ENABLED is passed to JMeter process using `-D` option) and inside that controller add "Test Action" sampler with "Stop now" action.

Comment: This did not work. Your solution looks to decide whether to run the test after the Jmeter  Application comes up. Whereas I want to Disable certain tests by default as soon as the Application comes up and not when I select the Run option.

Comment: Is there a way that I can set the enabled attribute by a  command line argument for a Generic Controller component

Comment: @Supriya, it worked for me, and as far as I know there is no other options for that except that you right your own plugin for JMeter i.e. Thread Group or Controller. Another possbility is that you preprocess your *.jmx file to disable certain parts of it using some scripting langauge like Perl or Groovy.

Comment: I tried your method of work around( without caring for the UI).. IN this case, the Sampler execution show random behavior.Also, it stop the current thread execution whereas I just want it to skip the current controller and move to the next controller and evaluate the enable variable once again.