# Enabling or Disabling Threads in jmeter from cmd using -J option

Tags: python, eclipse, cmd, jmeter

I am new to jmeter and i have the following query.

I am currently working on a project which involves me testing a jmx file containing multiple Threads. I am manually enabling or disabling the Simple Controllers as of now before running. I tried searching online and found the following solution to enabling or disabling from the cmd using the -J option.

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181878/jmeter-testing-configuration)

The problem is that this is not working out for me. I am using the following command in cmd

> > jmeter.bat -n -t C:\pathtojmx\testfile.jmx -l  C:\pathtooutput\JMETER_OUTPUT.xml -Jcondition1=true -Jcondition=true

The tree structure of the jmx file is as follows:

> > Thread 1: (condition 1)
> >
> > > > Thread 2 (child of Thread 1) ( condition 2).

The output i get from running this command is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">

</testResults>
```

I am running the jmeter from eclipse using the subprocess option. Earlier when i tried without the -J options, i was able to get the output from the test successfully into the file i specified.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** **:**

I have one Thread group in the jmx file with multiple Simple Controllers.
Since i am new to Jmeter i did not know this. 
So I had added and IF controller in each of the Simple Controllers with the condition specified.
Is it possible to disable Simple Controllers or o i have to create a new Test.jmx file with multiple thread groups.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what do you call "Thread".

If "Thread" stands for [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - you can set number of threads to zero via -J command-line argument for the Thread Groups you don't intend to run.

If "Thread" is for some [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - you need to put the sampler **as a child** of the If Controller. In that case put the following expression into the "Condition" input:

```
"${__P(condition,)}"=="true"
```

Comment: could you please explain a bit more on the Thread Group part i.e. setting the argument for threads i do not intend to run to zero.

Comment: Also i tried the "${__P(condition,)}"=="true"part by adding it in an IF controller and setting the action to stop now. But it still does not seem to work. The Thread groups are not getting enabled during the test.